# AppleScript Unable to escape multiple quotes within curl command

Tags: curl, applescript

I'm trying to run a curl command within apple script where I'm doing the following:

```
set trial_1 to "/somepath"

set output to do shell script ("export TRIAL_1=" & trial_1)

set output to do shell script ("curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{\"desiredCapabilities\":{"xcodeConfigFile\":quoted form of output}}'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub/session")
```

This is taking the "quoted form of output" as the parameter and running. What I'm trying to do is run with the variable value of output.

When I try the curl command on the terminal

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{\"desiredCapabilities\":{"xcodeConfigFile\":"'"$TRIAL_1"'"}}'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub/session,
```

it works like a charm. How Do i pass the same within applescript?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trial I got it.

set output to do shell script ("curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{\"desiredCapabilities\":{"xcodeConfigFile\":\"'\"$TRIAL_1\"'\"}}'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub/session")